# Rectangles of the area under the curve of any function

Tags: r, integral

I am struggling in writing a code that would produce a plot of any function with rectangle overlay of the area under the function for a specific interval. I see many examples of density functions with histograms but I want my rectangle to be bound by the function curve. We can take a function like x^2 as an example. Can someone help?
something like this:

Image reference:
https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section08.06.html

I tried different codes but I am new to R.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to share code you’ve tried so far, along with any relevant output or data? Please copy and paste your code directly into your post as text, not as a screenshot or image.

Comment: Those are just rectangles, no histograms.

Answer (score 1):

The function can be improved further.
As I understand something like that is what you expected.

```r
# ... additional barplot arguments
hist_for_fun <- function(fun, x_min, x_max, npoints, round = 3, ...) {
  stopifnot(is.function(fun))
  stopifnot(is.numeric(x_min) && (length(x_min) == 1) && is.numeric(x_max) && (length(x_max) == 1))
  stopifnot(is.numeric(fun(x_min)) && is.numeric(fun(x_max)))
  stopifnot(is.numeric(npoints) && (length(npoints) == 1))
  stopifnot(is.numeric(round)  && (length(round) == 1))
  
  x <- round(seq(x_min, x_max, length = npoints), round)
  y <- vapply(x, fun, numeric(1))
  barplot(y ~ x, space = 0, ...)
}

any_fun <- function(x) x**3 + x**2 + 3*x + 10

hist_for_fun(any_fun, -10, 10, 11)
```

[image]

```r
hist_for_fun(any_fun, -100, 100, 11)
```

[image]

```r
hist_for_fun(any_fun, -10, 10, 101)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I was able to create something similar but it does not scale well for lower values of the hist columns. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
xs <- seq(0, 1, length=1000)
ys <- sin(xs*2*pi) + 1 + 0.1*xs

N <- 10
points <- seq(min(xs), max(xs), length=N)
yPoints <- approx(xs, ys, points)[[2]]
plot(xs, ys, typ="l", col="blue", lwd=3)
for (i in 2:N) {
  polly <- rbind( c(points[i - 1], 0), c(points[i], 0), 
                 c(points[i], yPoints[i]), c(points[i - 1], yPoints[i - 1]))
  polygon(polly, col="lightyellow")
  lines(xs, ys, col="blue", lwd=3)  #puts line ontop of polygons
}
```

[image: Polygons under a curve]